# MongoDb multiple sort

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and have been struggling on getting multiple sorts using java apis  for a very long time now.

So my data is in the form of :

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "name":"sam",
   "timestamp":"2015-10-24 19:50:53"
}
```

I am trying to get the most recent 10 records based on the timestamp. Once I have that I want to sort the result based on name and timestamp.

This gives me the correct sorted outpt of recent 10 records :
 .sort(new Document("timestamp", -1)).limit(10)

But if i add more sort parameters it sorts the entire resultset.

I am trying to get the recent 10 records and once I have the result I want to sort by timestamp in ascending order and then by name in case of tie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that what you are trying to do is impossible. As described in [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods) sort is always executed before limit. So doing something like

```
.sort({timestamp: -1}).limit(10).sort({timestamp: 1, name: 1})
```

will just cause the first sort to be overwritten by the second sort.
This is just equivalent to

```
sort({timestamp: 1, name: 1}).limit(10)
```

So i think, that your best bet is to fetch 10 newest records from Mongo and then sort them again in Java code in order you need (timestamp ascending and name ascending).